# How to replace hyperlink with text in dojo EnhanceGrid?

Tags: dojo, dojox.grid.datagrid, dojox.grid, dojo.gridx

I am using dojo EnganceGrid which have 5 columns and the fifth column is image hyperlink. I want to replace hyperlink with text particular row of column. For example, I am clicking on 2nd row of fifth column. When I will click on image and My image hyperlink replace with some text. Can any one help to fix this issue?

```
For example 
<th field="mobileNumber"  noresize="true" formatter="formatMobileNumber" width="10" cellClasses="alignTextCenter">Mobile Number</th>

<span style="display:none" id="defaultFormatMobileNumber_${ns}">
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="showMobileNumber(event,valueToChange)">
<img src='/images/mobile.png' />
</a>
</span>

function formatMobileNumber(data, rowId){
var link = dojo.byId('defaultFormatMobileNumber').innerHTML;
link = link.replace("valueToChange",rowId);
return link
}

function showMobileNumber_<p:namespace/>(e,rowIdx){
//here I want to replace my link with some text
}
```

Comment: Please post you code

Answer (score 0):

The text that you want to show should be returned by the formatter. You could have `showMobileNumber` set some variable, say `clickedRow`, to the clicked row number and adapt `formatMobileNumber` to take that variable into account:

```js
clickedRow = -1;

function formatMobileNumber(data, rowId){
  if (clickedRow != rowId) {
    var link = dojo.byId('defaultFormatMobileNumber').innerHTML;
    link = link.replace("valueToChange",rowId);
    return link;
  }
  else {
    return "some text";
  }
}

function showMobileNumber_<p:namespace/>(e,rowIdx){
  clickedRow = rowIdx;
  // now the grid should probably be refreshed so that the formatter is 
  // re-applied. If variable 'grid' holds the grid:
  // grid._refresh();
}
```